# ACF in WooCommerce mail template

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I am using https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ plugin in WooCommerce and I have set a custom field named `"sub_domain"`.
I am trying to display the value of this custom field in the Woocommerce template `woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php`
After some research on the internet i found and used that code in to the `woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php` but it isn't working as like i expected:

```
<?php 
// Get the $order ID (WooCommerce version compatibility) 
if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) { 
$order_id = int_val( $order->id ); // Older than 3.0 
} else { $order_id = int_val( $order->get_id() ); // 3.0+ 
} $domain = get_field('sub_domain', $order_id );
if( $domain ){ echo '<p>' . $domain . '</p>'; } 
?>
```

the result is my site gets down whenever i try to make a new order (from backend). Do you have any idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where is the custom field? On orders, or products?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I am sorry I forgot to mention it, the custom field is on Subscriptions. I am using SUMO Subscription plugin and the custom field (domain) has been made at the list of the Subscriptions